# Просмотр скрытого function.php

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, php-frameworks

На сайте есть некий functions.php

Как его можно просмотеть?

`view-source:http://www.example.com` не проходит.

Comment: @Adam Knight, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Есть такие пути:

- взломать сайт (но это может быть чревато всякими последствиями);
- заказать взлом (но это ничуть не лучше предыдущего метода);
- попросить админа за чашкой его любимого напитка (чуть менее опасно);
- купить датацентр, где хостится сайт и посмотреть самостоятельно (дорого, да и последствия могут быть серьезные);
- забыть о этом желании (дешево, без последствий, рекомендуемый способ).

Кстати, там этого файла может и не быть. А по факту на пару с апачем будет работать один перлолый скрипт, который все будет генерить.

Comment: А просто посмотереть файл нельзя?  
На файл идет ссылка

    <form name="ххх"  method="post" action="http://ххх.php" id="ззз" onSubmit="return ValidateFormххх()">

Comment: Нет, обычно нельзя. Он исполняется на сервере.

Comment: а не обычно это как ? можно по подробней ?

Comment: А никак!..

Comment: Можно поподробней?// если у сервака левые настройки и нет директивы исполнять php как php.

Comment: @knes ...и нет директивы исполнять php как php.

А если такой директивы нет, то Вам простой 

   view-source:http://www.example.com

подойдет.

Comment: Может и исполнять не стоит директива, но может быть файл прикрыт другими директивами, не дающими его посмотреть. Да банально может не хватать прав.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипты php, если сервер работает исправно, при обращении исполняются при помощи обработчика. Исходный код не показывается.

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) ответил абсолютно верно. Но все зависит от задачи.

Если вам надо получить доступ к тому, к чему доступа не дают, то это-таки взлом в любом случае. Смело пункты 1, 2, 3, т.е. попытка взлома сайта.

Если надо доработать какой-то модуль, который обращается удаленно, попросите документацию или сам файл. Это легально.

Если вам просто интересно, как работает какая-то функция, то либо-таки попросите автора рассказать, либо опишите результат работы тут и, возможно, вас натолкнут на мысль, как сделать такую же. Последнее - самое предпочтительное, вдруг и правда какая-то очень интересная функция?